# TypeScript import : Failed to load resource (404)

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core

I am coding my first typescript file and I have issue with package import.

The package I would like to use in my project is called [showdown](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/showdown)

**libman.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "library": "showdown@1.9.1",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/showdown/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Snowdown files downloads through **libman** to **wwwroot**

[image]

My **site.ts** file looks like

```
import { showdown } from "../lib/showdown/showdown";

function ConvertMarkdownToHtml(markdown) {
    var converter = new showdown.Converter({ tables: true, strikethrough: true });
    var html = converter.makeHtml(markdown);
    return html;
}
```

I import the underlying **site.js** file to the webpage through script tag with module type.

[image]

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="module" src="~/js/site.js"></script>
}
```

But I am getting following error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found)

[image]

What am I missing ?

**Update**

the *404* error is related to *site.js* file.

it looks like, that *site.js* is not generated at all, because in *site.ts* is a mistake

[image]

```
../lib/showdown/ showdown has no exported member showdown
```

the following change do not throw any error

```
import * as showdown from "../lib/showdown/showdown";

export function ConvertMarkdownToHtml(markdown) {
    var converter = new showdown.Converter({ tables: true, strikethrough: true });
    var html = converter.makeHtml(markdown);
    return html;
}
```

but how I can call the `ConvertMarkdownToHtml` from the html file ?

Comment: Which file results in a 404? Is it site.js? How did you build it? To use this in the browser you need to build the app with something like webpack or browserify.

Comment: @derpirscher you are right, it is `site.js`. I update the question with error message I have in `site.ts`. The typescript is build in visual studio in .net core project, I did not made any configuration. But it seems that default configuration contains `es5` as target (when I add `tsconfig.json` through wizard).

Comment: Well you will need to read the docs for that package you are trying to use. Seems it does not export the member you are trying to import from it. you can try `import showdown from "../lib/showdown/showdown"` or `import * as showdown from "..."`

Comment: @derpirscher yes I figured it right now :-) `import * as showdown from "..."` seems to work, I also add `export` keyword to `ConvertMarkdownToHtml` function but I still don't know how to call that function ?

Comment: @Muflix I don't think you need to add the `export` to the `ConvertMarkdownToHtml` function since it is compiled to `.js` file (which is then referenced using a `script` tag in HTML on your page), you just need to call the function inside your page and it should be working normally (if the compilation of the `.ts` file is successfull).

Comment: @Paul-LouisMas When I remove the export keyword I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: ConvertMarkdownToHtml is not defined`. When I remove the import keyword and create simple function like `function alertSum(a: number, b: number){ let result = a + b; alert(result); }` and call the function from script tag without `type="module"`, the simple funtion works ! But still I don't know how to call the function when there is an import keyword in the .js file (using modules) ?!

Comment: If I import the script with `type="module"` containing following code `import * as showdown from "../lib/showdown/showdown";
(function() { alert('x'); })();` the developer tools does not throw any javascript error, but the alert window does not show up.

Comment: EDIT: moved my comment to answer to use code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed @Paul-Louis Mas answer with tip described [here](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/)

**index.html**

```
@section Scripts {

    <script src="~/lib/showdown/showdown.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="module">
         import { ConvertMarkdownToHtml } from "./dist/site.js"
    
         var html = ConvertMarkdownToHtml('...');
    </script>
```

**site.js**

```
declare var showdown: any;
export function ConvertMarkdownToHtml(markdown) {
    var converter = new showdown.Converter({ tables: true, strikethrough: true });
    var html = converter.makeHtml(markdown);
    return html;
}
```

and it works :-)

- the `declare var showdown: any;` is the key how to use external js library without solving countless compile errors. Disadvantage is that we do not have intellisense available this way.

Answer (score 1):

After having Googled around a bit, it seems that you can't use imports from modules globally, so have you tried this:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="module">
        import { ConvertMarkdownToHtml } from '~/js/site.js';

        // Do the logic here using ConvertMarkdownToHtml
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but it works only partially. I'am now getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'showdown' of undefined`. I also tried import the jQuery `import * as $ from "../lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"` and it says `$ is not a function` when I try to use it, so I have probably issue with model resolution. If I try `"../lib/jquery/dist/jquery"` or `"jquery"` paths, the error is the same but I triple checked the correct location.

Comment: If I try some custom class for example
`import { Greeter } from "./greeter.js"
export function ConvertMarkdownToHtml(markdown) {
    let greeter = new Greeter("world");
    alert(greeter.greet())
}` it works ! **The issue seems to be only with external JS packages** (like `jQuery` or `showdown`).

Comment: Ah, maybe it's because of the ways packages (like showdown and jQuery) are exported, maybe they do not use the `export` because you use a browser version that is meant to be loaded using `window.showdown` or `window.$`. Maybe on their website is a module that use `export`